# Exception with connection in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to learn ADO.NET to connect with SQL Server ... 
I install SQL Server with Visual Studio .... 
there is data base called "Northwind" as example with it ... 
I am trying to read this database , I wrote this code ...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DataSetReaderFromSQL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=SSPI;" + "Initial Catalog=Northwind");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "Select CustomerID , CompanyName from Customers";
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
                Console.WriteLine(reader["CustomerID"] +""+ reader["CompanyName"]);
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

When the application runs, it's take a little of time then throw exception when it trys to open connection ... 
the text of the exception :

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

I am using Windows 7 as my operating system, and I put username on my account ... 
I am sure that SQL Server was installed on my computer 
where is my error ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

- You haven't configured Sql Server to allow remote connections, as the error message tells you =)
- Your datasource is wrong. Try `.\SqlExpress` or just `.` Ordinarily when Visual Studio installs Sql Server Express, it installs it as a named instance called SqlExpress.

Comment: thanks ... yes I wasn't configured Sql Server ... 
when I do that and put sqlexpress in Data source text .... 
a new exception is thrown ... 
((cannot open data set "MyDataBase" request by the login . The login failed . Login failed for user "Farah-PC/Farah" )) .

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio includes [Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express) edition of SQL Server. Thus, your connection string should most likely look like `"Data Source=(local)\sqlexpress;..."`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick & easy way to try different connection strings, I suggest [DatabaseTester](http://www.sql-reports.net/2011/03/how-to-easily-test-your-adonet-connections.html) (disclaimer - I wrote it). It's free and a very easy way to test. Also, for figuring out connections strings [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) is your best friend.